# Find numbers using regular expression with egrep in Linux terminal

Tags: regex, linux, terminal

I want to find all separated words (which means characters between two spaces), that are decimal numbers including plus and minus signs in Linux terminal using `egrep`.

My solution:

```
(?<= |\n|\t)[\+\-]?[0-9]+(?= |\n|\t)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<= |\n|\t)` checks if there is a space or newline or tabulator before decimal number
- `(?= |\n|\t)` checks if there is a space or newline or tabulator after decimal number.

This code works well in program Kiki 0.5.6 where I test implementation, but if I copy it to terminal, it doesn't work. I think that terminal doesn't recognize special parentheses constructions `(?=` or `?<=)`. Am I right? How can I apply to terminal?

For example: my text:

```
1.fasfa
123asfavdsvdas156
1safsavdsvsd1sdva5s31as35d1va
595s6dva2sdvas9
asd9as5dv92s
sd559vs fs5s94 4dfs dfa4s44 459    9dasf 8sdfa 5sfa
napr. uNIveRziTA
sfaf 2262 2226 56565 adss
uNiVerZita
uNIVERZITa
123
123 sadasf 123456 sfafs 134
-1234- -25- -5- 5- --55
-
-55
123 100 999 124 6262 62 6 2 62 62 65 26565 22 62 62652 +665 +0649  ---662 265 959 595 099 199 -059 -0245 -444
--1245 -555-5-55 --555- 555-
+25
 -55 
+++55 +5 ++5 ++55+665+
samo samo  samo   samo otec otec skola skola     samo lamo samo lamo
re20. (?<=(\t|\n| ))([+-])?[1-9][0-9]*(?= |$|\n)
--- ---
doma doma doma doma doma doma doma doma doma
meno.priezvisko@tuke.sk meno.priezvisko.1@tuke.sk meno.priezvisko@student.tuke.sk meno.priezvisko.2@student.tuke.sk

23:56:59.555
00:00:00.000
23:59:59.999

31/12/2099
00/12/2054
01/01/2000
```

matches:

```
459
2262
2226
56565
123
123
123456
134
-55
123
100
999
124
6262
62
6
2
62
65
26565
22
62
62652
+655
+0649
```

Comment: what is the exact command your are running?

Comment: The problem isn't with the terminal. The problem is that you're taking Kiki regex syntax and using it in egrep. No two tools have exactly the same regex syntax.

Comment: I wanted to reduce the size of your examples, but it wasn't clear to me how they matched up. I'm guessing this is what you're getting, not what you want to get? I suggest you show both, shorten the input lines to avoid horizontal scroll, and shorten all lists to reduce reader effort.

Answer (score 1):

`egrep` does not support lookaround assertions. However, GNU grep comes with perl compatible regular expressions using the `-P` switch:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\s|^)[+-]?[0-9]+(?=\s|$)' input
```

Note that you can simplify `|\n|\t` to `\s` which stands for *whitespace character*. In order to match numbers that start at the begin of a line and numbers that end at the end of the line I've added `^` and `$` as alternatives for `\s`.

Comment: This expression won't match lines containing just `123` and no whitespace. You need something like `(?<=\s|^)[+-]?[0-9]+(?=\s|$)`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Good point. IMHO you are right, even if the OP clearly states `I want to find all separated words (which means characters between two spaces)`. I've added your suggestion.